# Boids particles - setting Render as Object breaks simulation

Tags: particles, physics

I have a boids system that moves its particles to a Goal avoiding certain objects.
This works fine when I'm testing with Render as Halo.
As soon as I change Render to an Object, or Collection, the simulation breaks and most of the particles slow down to a halt shortly after leaving the emitter.
Changing back to Render as Halo does not fix the issue.
Any idea what may be causing this?
initial state
[image: initial state]
final state with Render as Halo
[image: final state with Render as Halo]
final state with Render as Object
[image: final state with Render as Object]

[image]

Comment: it is nice that you provided a blend file which WOULD help. But...i am not willing to ask for permission to open that. You want help. So make it easy for us to help. And you should use https://blend-exchange.com/ to provide blend files.

Comment: I wasn't aware of blend-exchange. File attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you changed the scale of your object, when you changed to render as object, right?

Just leave the scale as it is

[image]

and select your icosphere.
Press tab to enter edit mode, press A to select all then S to scale and scale this little guy up until you see enough and run simulation again.

result:

[image]

Comment: That's it @Chris, thanks a lot!
Do you know if this is how that's supposed to work though? Shouldn't a particle scale of 1.0 give the same size object (also set to scale 1.0) ?
The Manual does not explain how it works exactly. I have another system where Render Scale is set to 1.0, which makes the particle size the same as the referenced object. There's no collisions or avoidance in that one though so I'm suspecting it's got something to do with who they're calculated.

Comment: yes, if the scale is set to 1, the particle size is exactly the size of the referenced object. Then you can easily size the particle by just sizing your object in edit mode and they have the same size. I don't know what connection this has to the halo size though. And i don't know either why the scaled objects behaving differently... sorry.

Comment: No worries. You've solved my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome